# How to check if a constructor is assigned/initialized

Tags: python

I have a code snippet as following

```
A = a_class()
C= Another_Class(A)

B = b_class()
C = Another_Class(B)
```

I would like to check / raise errors when A or B is None or if Another_Class(X) when X is not A or B.

Thanks.

Comment: I think `A=None` and A being an object with`self.some_property=None` bith are different. Whar are you looking for? In second scenario I think you can use `isinstance()`

Comment: Neither `A` nor `B` can be `None` unless you are are specifically overriding their `__new__` methods. It's not clear what your condition involving `Another_Class` is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't quite understand your question but to check if any variable is `None` you can do an `if`:

```
if A == None or B == None:
  raise Exception
```

To raise an Exception when to instantiate a new object, just code the rule inside of `__init__` method. This example considers that `ClassA` and `ClassB` have the same Parent, so for any child you can check if they have the same Parent:

```
def __init__(self, attr):
  if not isinstance(attr, Parent):
    raise Exception
```

Full example:

```
def main():
  A = ClassA()
  B = ClassB()
  X = ClassX()

  if A == None or B == None:
    raise Exception

  # Do not raise Exception
  anotherClass = AnotherClass(A)
  # Raise exception cause X doesn't inherit from Parent
  anotherClass = AnotherClass(X)

class Parent(object):
  pass

class ClassA(Parent):
  pass

class ClassB(Parent):
  pass

class ClassX(object):
  pass

class AnotherClass(object):
  def __init__(self, attr):
    if not isinstance(attr, Parent):
      raise Exception

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```